# Dual boot Kali with Mac

Tags: mac, unix, dual-boot

I want to dual my Macbook with Mavericks 10.9.4 and Kali 1.0.8. I have downloaded the Kali .iso and "burnt" it to a USB stick using the dd command from in Terminal. I have partitioned my hard drive and left 50GB for Kali. I want to boot from the USB to install Kali (I'm pretty sure this is the way you are supposed to do it). However, when I hold down the option key at boot time and select the USB, my MacBook freezes. I have read stuff on google about grub. I am supposed to use that to make it boot? What do I need to do to have a dual boot Mac/Kali system?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly I'd suggest running it in a virtual machine (VM). I used to dual boot, however, at every update it would wipe the Kali install.

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation#Detailed_How-To may also provide more detailed information.

Comment: I tried using rEFInd. If I boot into the Kali USB using rEFInd it gives a list of errors (all the same): `Error: not found from LocateDevicePath` and it tells me to press any key to continue, which takes me back to the rEFInd menu.

Comment: I also thought the rEFInd tool was only needed for booting into OSs that don't support EFI booting. Kali 1.0.8 does support it so would I need to use rEFInd?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an external cd drive then burning the live cd to disk and booting from that (the windows option not the efi option)  will boot. But it does not appear to have drivers for wifi.